# Why isn't this .replace code working, It may be something with def function

Tags: python, str-replace

So, I'm trying to make a secret code maker and I'm using the replace function to change the letters. Now, when I do one line like so:

```
x = 'example'
print(x.replace('e', 'f'))
```

that works fine, but I don't want to print multiple lines (I'm doing the whole alphabet) for example:

```
x = 'example'
print(x.replace('e', 'f'))
print(x.replace('x', 'e'))
```

like that. I don't want to have multiple lines, I want it done in one.

I've tried using the def function to figure this out but I'm confused here and absolutely stuck. Here's what I have:

```
> message = 'abc'

> def replacer(message):
>>    message.replace("a", "!")
>>    message.replace("b", '1')
>>    message.replace('c', '@')
>>    message.replace('d', '2')

> print(replacer.message)
```

I want it to output abc as !1@ but all I get is an error, here it is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(replacer.message)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Comment: Are you going to replace some letters with other letters or only symbols? In the first case, careful you might replace your replacements. I might have a solution for that then. In the other case, don't mind this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` method does not work in-place. What this means is that **calling it will not modify the object.** This is something you cannot do, because `string` objects are immutable.

You need to do `message = message.replace("a", "!")` and not just `message.replace("a", "!")`.

Also your function needs to `return message`, and then you can see it by writing `print(replacer(message))` (not `print(replacer.message)`).

Comment: When I ran this it gave the output of None.

Comment: That's because you did not read carefully. The function needs to `return message`

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should start to assign the result to a variable and also, when you define a functione (with `def`), you should return something. Like this:

```
message = 'abc'

def replacer(message):
  message = message.replace("a", "!")
  message = message.replace("b", '1')
  message = message.replace('c', '@')
  message = message.replace('d', '2')
  return message

print(replacer(message))
```

This will print your desired output of `!1@`.

Comment: Just want to clarify does `.replace()` method not work in place ?

Comment: I don't think so, at least not in python 3. Just tried it myself [here](https://repl.it/repls/IncompleteGlassProblem).

Answer (score 1):

`.replace()` does not work without reassignment, because as others have noted strings are immutable. It is best to think of `.replace()` as a function that *returns* the altered string, which then needs to be captured into a variable, instead of a method available to string objects. For example:

```
message = "Hello there!"
message.replace("H", "F")
print(message)
```

Yields:

> "Hello there!"

With no replacement. To avoid this you need to reassign the variable such as:

```
message = "Hello there!"
message = message.replace("H", "F") # reassign variable
print(message)
```

Yielding the expected:

> "Fello there!"

Next, `replacer` has no attribute `.message`, but it is an argument that expects an *input variable* which it will assign to the *local variable* `message`(which shadows your global variable `message`, probably leading to part of your confusion. Typically local and global namespaces should be different!)

Finally, your function doesn't `return` anything. I suggest you review [`return` statements](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/python/return-statement/) to learn about this functionality.

A functional script would therefore look like:

```
message = 'abc'

def replacer(input_message): # different namespace for local variable
    input_message = input_message.replace("a", "!") #reassign output
    input_message = input_message.replace("b", '1') #reassign output
    input_message = input_message.replace('c', '@') #reassign output
    input_message = input_message.replace('d', '2') #reassign output
    return input_message # make the function give you something useful back

print(replacer(message)) # give the function an input instead of trying to access a method/attribute of it
```

Running this updated script yields a more appropriate:

> "!1@"